# How to create new environment based on subequations

Tags: numbering, environments, subequations

I've created new environment based on equation for chemical reactions that use roman numbers. I would like to create another environment based on subequations that use this numbering format. Below you can find the MWE.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,openright,12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcounter{chemEquationCounter}[chapter]
\renewcommand*\thechemEquationCounter{\thechapter. \Roman{chemEquationCounter}}
\newenvironment{chemEquation}{%
\stepcounter{chemEquationCounter}%
\begin{equation}%
}%
{\tag{\thechemEquationCounter}%
\end{equation}%
}

\newenvironment{mathSubEquations}%
{%
\begin{subequations}%
    \renewcommand{\theequation}{\theparentequation-\alph{equation}%
    }
}%
{%
\end{subequations}%
}%

\newenvironment{chemSubEquations}%
{%
\begin{subequations}%
    \renewcommand{\theequation}{\theparentequation-\alph{equation}%
    }
}%
{%
\end{subequations}%
}%

\newenvironment{eqs}
{\subequations\align}
{\endalign\endsubequations}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1}

\begin{equation}
    a=b.c
\end{equation}

\begin{chemEquation}
    2H_2 + O_2 \rightarrow 2H_2O
\end{chemEquation}

\begin{mathSubEquations}
    \begin{equation}
        a=b.c
    \end{equation}
    \begin{equation}
        d=e.f
    \end{equation}
\end{mathSubEquations}

\begin{chemSubEquations}
    \begin{chemEquation}
    CH_4 + O_2 \rightarrow CO_2 + 2H_2O
    \end{chemEquation}
    \begin{chemEquation}
    NaOH + HCl \rightarrow NaCl + H_2O
    \end{chemEquation}
\end{chemSubEquations}
\end{document}
```

that give's me:[image]
I want chemical reactions to appear like math equations. But as you could see chemical reactions below are formatted different. The numbering also is completely wrong. What I am missing?

Comment: (1) the `memoir` tag is not relevant here, (2) might be an idea if you explained what you then actually wanted instead of just writing that it is not what you want.

Comment: @daleif memoir tag removed.

Comment: (1) remember to use `chchem` to format the chemetry, (2) you are not using `\theequation` in your chemical equation, you are overwriting it using `\tag`

Comment: Isn't it `mhchem`? Also, `chemformula` is another possibility.